# How do I view standard out in hadoop?

Tags: hadoop

I'm new to hadoop and trying to get my first non-trivial program working, and want to view standard out for debugging purposes. It's my understanding that standard out is directed into log files somewhere, so my question is twofold. 1) where is the log file storing this output 2) how do I view the file?

FYI, I'm just running the code on tiny inputs in the virtual machine right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to your jobtracker web interface, there are links to view jobs, click on them, then go to map or reduce attempts, and for each task attempt there's a link to view logs for this task.

http://jobtracker:50060/tasklog?attemptid=attempt_201101171546_0109_m_000000_0&all=true

Comment: Where is the jobtracker web interface? BTW, I'm just running this on the vm. Does that also provide a web interface to the local host?

Comment: If you have network configured on vm this should work. In your browser enter http://ip_adress_of_vm:50060

Comment: @Wojtek: I tried following as you suggested, but I can see that the "stdout logs" section is empty. Do we have to following additional set of steps to turn on the "stdout logs"?

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out. I restarted jps, fixed one bug in my code which was not letting me reach to the println().