# printing to screen variables inside mapper

Tags: java, hadoop

I want to check the contents of an element that is in my map
functions, is there a way to print the contents of the variables
to the screen. It is very slow to work on this stuff when I can't
see what's in each of these variables. I have tried "System.out.println" 
but that doesn't seem to work inside the mapper.

```
public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context
               ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    String line = value.toString();
    System.out.println(line + "\n");
    String delimiter = "\t";
    String[] temp;

    temp = line.split(delimiter);

    for(int i =0; i < temp.length ; i++)
        System.out.println(temp[i]);

    StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
    while (itr.hasMoreTokens())
    {
        word.set(itr.nextToken().length() + "");
        context.write(word, one);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a `debugger` to view the contents of the variables instead? Also, I'm assuming that you're looking to `split` on a tab, correct? If so, I'd recommend using `"\\t"`.

Comment: \\t.. I have used \t and it works fine.. apparently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hadoop jobs are executed on remote servers, you can see STDOUT in jobtracker's web interface (see this question: [How do I view standard out in hadoop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721523/how-do-i-view-standard-out-in-hadoop/4722057) )

Answer (score 2):

Try running the job with the following format
`$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop -jar [your_jar_file]`
The `-jar` forces it to be run as a local job and will output to the console.

Comment: That's how I actually run it without the "-". It actually doesn't print inside the mapper function apparently. 
../bin/hadoop jar [my_jar_file]

Comment: @Flethuseo:Did you try running it with the `-`?

Comment: Yes, I get an error: 

Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from
/Users/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/wordcount/wordcount.jar